# Java simple sentence parser

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

is there any simple way to create sentence parser in plain Java
without adding any libs and jars.

Parser should not just take care about blanks between words,
but be more smart and parse: . ! ?,
recognize when sentence is ended etc.

After parsing, only real words could be all stored in db or file, not any special chars.

thank you very much all in advance :)

Comment: Also consider [`StreamTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html); it's [fast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082174/230513) and accommodates whitespace flexibly.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to start by looking at the [BreakIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) class.

From the JavaDoc.

> The BreakIterator class implements
>   methods for finding the location of
>   boundaries in text. Instances of
>   BreakIterator  maintain a current
>   position and scan over text returning
>   the index of characters where
>   boundaries occur. Internally,
>   BreakIterator scans text using a
>   CharacterIterator, and is thus able to
>   scan text held by any object
>   implementing that protocol. A
>   StringCharacterIterator  is used to
>   scan String objects passed to setText.
>
> You use the factory methods provided
>   by this class to create instances of
>   various types of break iterators. In
>   particular, use getWordIterator,
>   getLineIterator, getSentenceIterator,
>   and getCharacterIterator to create
>   BreakIterators that perform word,
>   line, sentence, and character boundary
>   analysis respectively. A single
>   BreakIterator can work only on one
>   unit (word, line, sentence, and so
>   on). You must use a different iterator
>   for each unit boundary analysis you
>   wish to perform.
>
> Line boundary analysis determines
>   where a text string can be broken when
>   line-wrapping. The mechanism correctly
>   handles punctuation and hyphenated
>   words.
>
> Sentence boundary analysis allows
>   selection with correct interpretation
>   of periods within numbers and
>   abbreviations, and trailing
>   punctuation marks such as quotation
>   marks and parentheses.
>
> Word boundary analysis is used by
>   search and replace functions, as well
>   as within text editing applications
>   that allow the user to select words
>   with a double click. Word selection
>   provides correct interpretation of
>   punctuation marks within and following
>   words. Characters that are not part of
>   a word, such as symbols or punctuation
>   marks, have word-breaks on both sides.
>
> Character boundary analysis allows
>   users to interact with characters as
>   they expect to, for example, when
>   moving the cursor through a text
>   string. Character boundary analysis
>   provides correct navigation of through
>   character strings, regardless of how
>   the character is stored. For example,
>   an accented character might be stored
>   as a base character and a diacritical
>   mark. What users consider to be a
>   character can differ between
>   languages.
>
> BreakIterator is intended for use with
>   natural languages only. Do not use
>   this class to tokenize a programming
>   language.

**See demo**: [BreakIteratorDemo.java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/BreakIteratorDemo.java)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@Jarrod Roberson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103619/854656), I have created a util method that uses BreakIterator and returns the list of sentences.

```
public static List<String> tokenize(String text, String language, String country){
    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);
    BreakIterator sentenceIterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(currentLocale);      
    sentenceIterator.setText(text);
    int boundary = sentenceIterator.first();
    int lastBoundary = 0;
    while (boundary != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        boundary = sentenceIterator.next();         
        if(boundary != BreakIterator.DONE){
            sentences.add(text.substring(lastBoundary, boundary));
        }
        lastBoundary = boundary;            
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular expression (`\s+` - it will apply to one or more whitespaces (spaces, tabs, etc.)) to split String into array.

Then you may iterate over that array and check whether word ends with `.?!` ([String.endsWith()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) to find end of sentences.

And before saving any word use once again regular expression to remove every non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, use StringTokenizer

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Token {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "Java! simple ?sentence parser.";
        String separator = "!?.";

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( sentence, separator, true );

        while ( st.hasMoreTokens() ) {
            String token = st.nextToken();
            if ( token.length() == 1 && separator.indexOf( token.charAt( 0 ) ) >= 0 ) {
                System.out.println( "special char:" + token );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "word :" + token );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you have a decimal number, it will not break on that correctly.

Answer (score -2):

[String Tokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

[Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Ex.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, " !?.");
```

Comment: what if you have a decimal number, it will not break on that correctly.

Comment: Same with abbreviations like Dr. or U.S.A.