# Extract digits from string - StringUtils Java

Tags: java, string, apache-stringutils, string-utils

I have a String and I want to extract the (only) sequence of digits in the string.

Example:
helloThisIsA1234Sample.
I want the 1234

It's a given that the sequence of digits will occur only once within the string but not in the same position.

(for those who will ask, I have a server name and need to extract a specific number within it)

I would like to use the StringUtils class from Apache commomns.

Thanks!

Comment: Apache [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html). Not sure why you wanna use it though.

Comment: That's what I have, was wondering if maybe there is a function already doing something like I need, but I am not so familiar with it

Comment: Cuz, when you can do it with `String` itself, you won't need the `StringUtils` from Apache.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use this code numberOnly will contain your desired output.

```
   String str="sdfvsdf68fsdfsf8999fsdf09";
   String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: String.replaceAll() would compile that pattern each time this is run. Really unoptimal. Check its source. Use Guava's CharMathcer.DIGIT.retainFrom() as seen below.

Comment: In more recent Java, the Regex can be simplified to "\\D"

Answer (score 39):

I always like using [Guava String utils](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) or similar for these kind of problems:

```
String theDigits = CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom("abc12 3def"); // 123
```

Comment: This is a lot faster than regular expression. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: use  CharMatcher.digit().retainFrom("xx123xx");  instead, DIGIT is scheduled to be removed in June 2018.

Comment: `CharMather.digit()` is also deprecated. I used `CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom("xx123xx");`

Answer (score 28):

Just one line:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `java.util.Scanner`:

`new Scanner(str).useDelimiter("[^\\d]+").nextInt()`

You can use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` to get the digits as a `String`. Note that calling `Integer.parseInt` on the result may be [many times faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423027/59087) than calling `nextInt()`.

You can check for the presence of number using `hasNextInt()` on the `Scanner`.

Comment: In more recent Java, the Regex can be simplified to "\\D"

Answer (score 7):

Use a regex such as `[^0-9]` to remove all non-digits.

From there, just use `Integer.parseInt(String);`

Comment: Sounds interesting, are you able to give me some more code? say my string var is called myString, how would I use it? (I am just a little new to Java...)

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
String s = "helloThisIsA1234Sample";
s = s.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

This means: replace all occurrences of digital characters (0 -9) by an empty string !

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a little explanation as to what your code does. :)

Answer (score 4):

Guava's `CharMatcher` class extracts `Integer`s from a `String`.

```
String text="Hello1010";
System.out.println(CharMatcher.digit().retainFrom(text));
```

Yields:

```
1010
```

Comment: Deprecated as of 2022

Answer (score 4):

Extending the best answer for finding floating point numbers

```
       String str="2.53GHz";
       String decimal_values= str.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", "");
       System.out.println(decimal_values);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a JUnit Test class(as a additional knowledge/info) for the same issue. Hope you'll be finding this helpful.

```
   public class StringHelper {
    //Separate words from String which has gigits
        public String drawDigitsFromString(String strValue){
            String str = strValue.trim();
            String digits="";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                char chrs = str.charAt(i);              
                if (Character.isDigit(chrs))
                    digits = digits+chrs;
            }
            return digits;
        }
    }
```

And JUnit Test case is:

```
 public class StringHelperTest {
    StringHelper helper;

        @Before
        public void before(){
            helper = new StringHelper();
        }

        @Test
    public void testDrawDigitsFromString(){
        assertEquals("187111", helper.drawDigitsFromString("TCS187TCS111"));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to org.apache.commons.lang3.
you can use StringUtils.getDigits method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "helloThisIsA1234Sample";
    System.out.println(StringUtils.getDigits(value));
}
output: 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
string.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        String line = "This order was32354 placed for QT ! OK?";
        String regex = "[^\\d]+";

        String[] str = line.split(regex);

        System.out.println(str[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");`

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string and compare with each character

```
public static String extractNumberFromString(String source) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(100);
    for (char ch : source.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

**Testing Code**

```
    @Test
    public void test_extractNumberFromString() {
    String numberString = NumberUtil.extractNumberFromString("+61 415 987 636");
    assertThat(numberString, equalTo("61415987636"));

    numberString = NumberUtil.extractNumberFromString("(02)9295-987-636");
    assertThat(numberString, equalTo("029295987636"));

    numberString = NumberUtil.extractNumberFromString("(02)~!@#$%^&*()+_<>?,.:';9295-{}[=]987-636");
    assertThat(numberString, equalTo("029295987636"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach if you have symbols and you want just numbers:

```
    String s  = "@##9823l;Azad9927##$)(^738#";
    System.out.println(s=s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s,"`~!@#$%^&*()-_+=\\.,><?");
    String s1 = "";
    while(tok.hasMoreTokens()){
        s1+= tok.nextToken();
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: This is now a slow solution, because String is immutable and in every cycle iteration is created new instance of String, replace at least with StringBuilder. Still it isn't write nice

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, if separated by comma or if not separated by comma

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "a,1,b,2,c,3,d,4";
    input = input.replaceAll(",", "");

    String alpha ="";
    String num = "";

    char[] c_arr = input.toCharArray();

    for(char c: c_arr) {
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
            alpha = alpha + c;
        }
        else {
            num = num+c;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Alphabet: "+ alpha);
    System.out.println("num: "+ num);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle decimal numbers and negative numbers you can use the following snippet:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mixedString);
String result = matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : null;
```

If you have a string like:

> The temperature is -12.5°

The above code will extract a String containing "-12.5", that can be then parsed using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`.

Answer (score -1):

```
   `String s="as234dfd423";
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
 {
    char c=s.charAt(i);``
    char d=s.charAt(i);
     if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
         System.out.println("String:-"+c);
     else  if ('0' <= d && d <= '9')
           System.out.println("number:-"+d);
    }
```

output:-

```
number:-4
number:-3
number:-4
String:-d
String:-f
String:-d
number:-2
number:-3
```

Comment: Your output doesn't appear to match your test input.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
  String str="java123java456";
  String out="";
  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
  {
    int a=str.codePointAt(i);
     if(a>=49&&a<=57)
       {
          out=out+str.charAt(i);
       }
   }
 System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: what about Capital letters or another languages?

Answer (score -6):

Simple  python code for separating  the digits in string

```
  s="rollnumber99mixedin447"
  list(filter(lambda c: c >= '0' and c <= '9', [x for x in s]))
```

Comment: this question has explicit Java tag