# Get all numbers from long string

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. How I can get only the numbers from this String:

```
folder333
```

Can you show me some basic example?

Also I would like to do this with Java 8.

Comment: What is number in your case? integer? Do you accept hexadeimal ones (e.g `0x456`)? Float? Should minuses (if any) be included into the number(s)? Could you provide a good test expample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974033/extract-digits-from-string-stringutils-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String number = str.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]*", "");
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov There is nothing specific here for Java 8.