# How to sort list with multiple condition?

Tags: java, android

I have ArrayList with name and id.

```
list.add(new Model2(null, "name1"));
list.add(new Model2("13", "name2"));
list.add(new Model2(null, "name1"));
list.add(new Model2("13", "name4"));
list.add(new Model2(null, "name1"));
list.add(new Model2("13", "name6"));
```

First if id is null and then by the name

```
//the result should by like this:
    //1. null , name1
    //2. null , name1
    //3. null , name1
    //4. 13,name2
    //5. 13,name4
    //6. 13,name6
```

I know how to sort the null values:

```
Collections.sort(list,sorting());   

    public static Comparator<? super Model2> sorting() {
        Comparator<Model2> sortedList = new Comparator<Model2>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Model2 o1, Model2 o2) {
                return o1.getId() == null ? -1 : 0;
            }
        };
        return sortedList;
    }
```

But what about the names values?

Comment: you looking for how to sort by the name or how to combine different properties for your sorting ?

Comment: try java's comparator interface and check whether you can achieve what you want. Tutorial http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to figure out how you want to compare two strings. Should **name2** come before **name10**, then you need to extract the number from the string. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974033/extract-digits-from-string-stringutils-java) how to do that.

You can order strings in many different ways, so I'll just describe the idea. In the **compare** method, you should have something like the following instead:

```
public int compare(Model2 o1, Model2 o2) {
    if (o1.getId() == null) return -1;
    else if (o2.getId() == null) return 1;
    else return compareStrings(o1.getName(), o2.getName());
}
```

The thing you have to consider here is how to implement the **compareStrings** method.

P.S. You can of course write it into a single return statement, but I thought if-statements would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Model2> list = new ArrayList<Model2>();

    list.add(new Model2(null, "name1"));
    list.add(new Model2("13", "name2"));
    list.add(new Model2(null, "name3"));
    list.add(new Model2(null, "name2"));
    list.add(new Model2("13", "name6"));
    list.add(new Model2("14", "name7"));
    list.add(new Model2("13", "name4"));
    list.add(new Model2("14", "name3"));

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model2>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Model2 o1, Model2 o2) {
            if (o1.getId() != null && o2.getId() != null) {
                if (o1.getId().equals(o2.getId())) {
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                }
                return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
            } else if (o1.getId() == null) {
                if (o2.getId() == null) {
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                }
                return -1;
            } else if (o2.getId() == null) {
                if (o1.getId() == null) {
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });

    for (Model2 model2 : list) {
        System.out.println(model2);
    }
}
```

Gives

```
Model2 [id=null, name=name1]
Model2 [id=null, name=name2]
Model2 [id=null, name=name3]
Model2 [id=13, name=name2]
Model2 [id=13, name=name4]
Model2 [id=13, name=name6]
Model2 [id=14, name=name3]
Model2 [id=14, name=name7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Comparator<? super Model2> sorting() {
        return new Comparator<Model2>() {
           final Comparator<Model2> idComparator = Comparator.comparing(Model2::getId);
           final Comparator<Model2> nameComparator = Comparator.comparing(Model2::getName);
            @Override
            public int compare(Model2 o1, Model2 o2) {
                var idCompResult = idComparator.compare(o1, o2);
                if(idCompResult != 0){
                   return idCompResult;
                }
                return nameComparator.compare(o1,o2);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).