# How to extract a sequence of 7 numbers from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, sequence

Say I have some `String` object containing `"This sentence was written on 2020-03-21 by person 1234567 at 07:23 hours"`.
How would I extract ONLY the `"1234567"` part of the string?
Maybe using a solution from this [Extract digits from string - StringUtils Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974033/extract-digits-from-string-stringutils-java) question, but I don't know how to limit the extracted numbers only on the desired sequence.

If I would use the `str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` on this string, I would get `"2020032112345670723"` which means that it extracts ALL of the numbers in a string, but I want ONLY the sequence containing a certain number of digits (in my case 7).

Also, the sequence will not always be in the same place, so using `substring(index from, index to)` will not work.

Comment: A bit complicated, admittedly, but you could split the `String` by whitespace(s) and check which one is pure numeric (the date won't be because of the hyphons).

Comment: Good idea, but not for my case because instead of "person" there could be a number in a name, eg. "person 12"

Comment: @mdenci using regular expressions you don't have to care about  the position in the string, you should definitely go with a Regex.

Comment: OK, you could check if that number has exactly 7 digits then, too... But in situations with a second number of 7 digits, even a regular expression would fail, too.

Comment: @deHaar no, it will simply return multiple matches of the expression, which is fine.

Comment: @mmika1000 Will that really be fine? OP would have to check which number is the desired one.

Comment: @deHaar well, maybe not for his particular task, but if this is a critical task where inconsistencies like that may occur, he should think of a complete different approach either way (--> not parsing this value from a String)

Comment: @mmika1000 yes, totally agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably do that using a **regular expression**. For seven adjacenct digits that would be `\d{7}` or even better `\b\d{7}\b` (thanks @AlexRudenko).

To do so you might wanna use the `Pattern` API:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// ...

Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{7}\\b");
Matcher m = digitPattern.matcher(<your-string-here>);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group();
    // prints just your 7 digits
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I just verified it and it's working fine.

(Pattern extraction taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

Comment: I'm getting an "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" error on Pattern.compile("\d{7}")

Comment: Just one comment - you may need to surround digits with `\b` to match a number containing _exactly_ 7 digits: `"\\b\\d{7}\\b"`

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the backslash in the Pattern to `"\\d{7}"`. I'm sorry, I thought I edited that already.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the number of digits is not always 7, I would use the regular expression

`" ([0-9]+) "`

The inner part `[0-9]+` find one or more digits. The spaces left and right of it ensure that the number is only found if surrounded by spaces, so the dates and times in your input string are ignored. The parentheses are used in combination with `group(1)` to return only the number without spaces around it.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{

    private static final Pattern regexp=Pattern.compile(" ([0-9]+) ");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s="This sentence was written on 2020-03-21 by person 1234567 at 07:23 hours";
        Matcher matcher=regexp.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            String number=matcher.group(1);
            System.out.printf("number=%s",number);
        }
    }
}
```

To find only numbers with 5 - 8 digits, you could write `" ([0-9]{5,8}) "`

As other wrote in the meantime, `\\d` may be used as an alternative to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `linear search` to find the `numeric` substring of `length` 7:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "This sentence was written on 2020-03-21 by person 1234567 at 07:23 hours";
        System.out.println(getNumber(str));
}
private static String getNumber(String str) {
        String number = null;
        if(str != null)
            for(String s : str.split(" "))
                if(s.length() == 7 && isNumeric(s))
                    number = s;
        return number;
}
private static boolean isNumeric(String str) { 
        try {  
              Integer.parseInt(str);  
              return true;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){  
              return false;  
        }  
}
```

Output:

```
1234567
```