# Scanner in java performance

Tags: java

I have a file with 100000 line when am using System.in it takes more than 1 minute to get the input but when I use a file to read the input it doesn't take time.
what is the solution to keep using System.in but with more speed?

Comment: i am a new user i accept questions but u know sometimes you cant what can i do!!!?

Comment: You can always accept an answer, just click the tick below the vote count on the left.

Comment: even if does not answer the subject how it  comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.in reads line by line not the file contents at a time.So it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` is inherently slow because it's taking the data in line by line (checking for newlines), rather than doing a large block copy from a file mapped in virtual memory.

There's no real way to speed up `System.in`, and this sounds like a situation where reading a file would be much more ideal.

**Update:** You may want to look at this question: [What's the fastest way to read from System.in in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049011/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-from-system-in-in-java)

Comment: am solving an acm problem and the input is from System.in

Comment: Could you not change it so the string that goes to `System.in` is a path to the file, then parse it out from there?

Comment: i wish :S it doesnt make any sense http://livearchive.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=378&page=show_problem&problem=2968

Comment: Updated post with a link, might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the stream of system.in
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(fileName));

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StringTokenizer if you want to read file very fast.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html