# Time limit exceeded even with best approach(Java)

Tags: java

Even if I think that I solved a competitive programming [problem from HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/easy-one-8/) with the best approach, all tests exceed the time limit. I really do not know how to optimize it further because it is just an easy exercise.

My approach: iterate over all array members than add them to a `HashMap` which stores their occurrences. After that simply read the query numbers and get their occurence from the `HashMap`.

This is my solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        //go through all test cases
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            String[] inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int N = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
            int Q = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
            inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");

            //read array
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(inputs[j]);
                Integer value = map.get(x);
                //if number is already in hashmap then increment its count
                //else put it into the map with a count of 1
                if (value == null) {
                    map.put(x, 1);
                } else map.put(x, value + 1);
            }

            //iterate through the queries and get their occurences from the map
            for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                Integer value = map.get(x);
                if (value == null) {
                    System.out.println(0);
                } else System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: what can be the problem with my approach? Why does it run out of time?

Comment: You should probably walk us through your approach via your question's description :)

Comment: description added :)

Comment: oh, sorry, that was only a typo. corrected

Comment: ok, so I think that I was lucky because in all test cases N=Q :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is not so obvious. I took a look at the input files and they are huge so you have to use some really fast method for writing to the console(many test cases -->> many answers). You can use `PrinteWriter` for that.

Working solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        //go through all test cases
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            String[] inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int N = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
            int Q = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
            inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");

            //read array
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(inputs[j]);
                Integer value = map.get(x);
                //if number is already in hashmap then increment its count
                //else put it into the map with a count of 1
                if (value == null) {
                    map.put(x, 1);
                } else map.put(x, value + 1);
            }

            //iterate through the queries and get their occurences from the map
            for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                Integer value = map.get(x);
                if (value == null) {
                    pr.println(0);
                } else pr.println(value);
            }
        }
        pr.close();
    }
}
```

Yes, I know that it is strange that the exercise itself is not so hard, but reading the input and writing the result is the big part of it.

Comment: Please do not take credit for a class that you did not create. This solution (taken from the #1 answer on the test site he is using) is unbelievably over optimized, and completely unintuitive for this problem,

Comment: yeap, I tested it and it works. But the method used for reading is just weird :)

Comment: @Philip DiSarro I modified my code removing that class. Even now it passes all test cases though it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is primarily it's use of BufferedReader, and the consequential information parsing you're preforming. Try an approach with scanner.

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = s.nextInt();       
        Map<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            int N=s.nextInt();
            int Q=s.nextInt();
            int[] arr=new int[N];
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                arr[j]=s.nextInt();
                if(map.containsKey(arr[j]))
                {
                    map.put(arr[j],map.get(arr[j])+1);
                }
                else
                map.put(arr[j],1);
            }
            for(int k=0;k<Q;k++)
            {
                int X=s.nextInt();
                if(map.containsKey(X)){
                    sb.append(map.get(X)+"\n");
                }
                else{
                    sb.append(0+"\n");
                }     
            }
             System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
            map.clear();
        }

    }
}
```

This will remove a lot of the unnecessary parsing you are doing with:

```
 String[] inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");
 int N = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
 int Q = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
 inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");
```

Please look at [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader) to understand why Scanner is situationally faster here. Essentially BufferedReader is faster in it's ability to simply read the lines, but when you use BufferedReader here, you are then forced to use `Integer.parseInt(...)` and `br.readlines().split(" ")` to parse the information you need from the input; however, scanner has built in parsing mechanisms that can read and parse the data asynchronously. As you will see, this approach passes the test in 4-8 seconds. Additionally you could benefit from using StringBuilder, and not using:

```
Integer value = map.get(x);
if (value == null) {
    pr.println(0);
} else pr.println(value);
```

With the built in method `map.containsKey(x)`.

> Scanner is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream while BufferedReader just reads the stream and does not do any special
>   parsing.
>
> In fact you can pass a BufferedReader to a scanner as the source of
>   characters to parse.

Furthermore:

> A scanner on the other hand has a lot more cheese built into it; it
>   can do all that a BufferedReader can do and at around the same level of
>   efficiency as well. However, in addition a Scanner can parse the
>   underlying stream for primitive types and strings using regular
>   expressions. It can also tokenize the underlying stream with the
>   delimiter of your choice. It can also do forward scanning of the
>   underlying stream disregarding the delimiter!

There is a large difference in runtime when you have to call 
`inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");` and `Integer.parseInt(..)` multiple times, versus simply calling `s.nextInt()`. You are already reading the data with `br.readLine()`, when you call `Integer.parseInt(...)` the data is read again by the `parseInt()` function.

Comment: [Scanner is slower than BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049011/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-from-system-in-in-java).

Comment: @Csaba Check out the edits, I've provided a little more background to why Scanner is situationally better here.

Comment: @PhilipDiSarro I'm not seeing much in the link your provided to indicate that Scanner is faster, situationally or otherwise. Scanner does similar checking as what you'd do with BufferedReader, just internally instead of letting the user do it themselves (and it also does more checking, as far as I'm aware). Your approach is not equivalent to OP's approach, which had a bug which might've caused the problem, so this working while that doesn't is not to say Scanner is faster.

Comment: @Dukeling I've added quotes from the top answers of the thread I specified. Scanner's `.nextInt()` function parses information much differently then `Integer.parseInt()` in that scanner reads and parses the data at the same time, whereas BufferedReader simply reads the data which means the data has to be  iterated through again by `Integer.parseInt()`. The scanner class is optimized for token parsing.

Comment: @PhilipDiSarro your method works, too but I think it works because you used StringBuilder to print the output. That is almost the same as using PrintWriter.