# Fast way to parse a string into int in Java

Tags: java, android, string, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read large amount of data from file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693223/read-large-amount-of-data-from-file-in-java)

I have a string like "2 -56 0 78 0 4568 -89..." end so on. Now I use `Scanner.nextInt()` to parse it, but it seems to be slow. Platform is Android. Any advices how to implement in for better speed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `myString.split(" ")`, which split on `' '`, then `Integer.valuesOf(..)`

Comment: StringTokenizer is not recommended for use in newer versions of Java, String split() is recommended.

Comment: @ChinBoon you are right, Modified.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` has always been faster than `String.split` for simple things like this.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string on the space and parse each entry

```
for (String s: string.split(" ")) {
  int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
  //do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go for reading the input as normal `String` and then using `Integer.parseInt()` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.split("\\s")` and then for each string use `Integer.valueOf()` to parse to an Integer or `Integer.parseInt()` to parse to an int.

Answer (score 1):

```
  you can use Integer.parseInt(Value of String);
```