# What is the fastest way to read from standard input in Scala?

Tags: performance, scala

What is the fastest way (in terms of performance) to read from standard input in Scala? 
Most interesting case for me is a lots of Integers as input.

Comment: In this aspect scala is no different from java -- for low level aspects such as working with system.in scala rely on java primitives.

Comment: Here's a very basic string tokenizer that is very fast if you only have a single delimiter: https://gist.github.com/jskorpan/1056060
StringTokenizer from Java may be fast enough for your needs.
It's deprecated, but it still outperforms the suggested replacements of string.split and the regular expressions library.

Comment: This may do better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2698772/779314

Comment: @om-nom-nom, does the BufferedInputStream from the second example not handle that case?