# Is there a simple way of parsing this text into a Map

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, parsing, groovy

I receive the response from a service as below. How to parse this into a `Map`? I first thought of split at whitespace but it doesn't work as the value might contain spaces e.g. look at the value of **SA** key in the below response.

One option I thought of is to split at whitespace **provided** the previous character is a double quote. Not sure how to write the regex for this though.

TX="0000000000108000001830001" FI="" OS="8" CI="QU01SF1S2032" AW="SSS" SA="1525 Windward Concourse"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse at quotes.  You could even use a regular expression to find each key/value pair, assuming each value is in quotes.  My only question would be, what are the rules for if a value contains embedded quotes?  (Are they escaped using '\' or such?  Regardless, this is not currently accounted for in the below...)

For example:

```
(\w+)="([^"]*)"
```

This will even give you groups #1 and #2 that can be used to provide the key and the value, respectively.

Run this in a loop, using Java's `Matcher.find()` method, until you find all of the pairs.

Sample code:

```
String input = "TX=\"0000000000108000001830001\" FI=\"\" OS=\"8\" CI=\"QU01SF1S2032\" AW=\"SSS\" SA=\"1525 Windward Concourse\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\w+)=\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*");

Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
TX
0000000000108000001830001
FI

OS
8
CI
QU01SF1S2032
AW
SSS
SA
1525 Windward Concourse
```

Comment: Geez, just use single quotes; it's tagged Groovy :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - We'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.  :-)

Comment: @ziesemer - +1. But I am getting the valaue after '=' printed with double quoes as "0000000000108000001830001"

Comment: @Pangea - because that's what it is in the input.  What do you expect?  "108000001830001"?  If so, you'll need to parse it to a number - but given the above sample input and requirements, I'm not sure how you'd determine which values should be handled as numbers, and which should be left handled as Strings.

Comment: @ziesemer - I asked the question because your sample output in the response doesn't contain double quotes. Seems like in need to use replaceAll() method to remove double quotes

Comment: @ziesemer - It doesn't contain the double quote after updating the latest code

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of the text it seems that it could be an XML. Is that so, or is that text the raw response of the service? If it is an XML you can parse it easily with Groovy's XmlSlurper:

```
def input = '<root TX="0000000000108000001830001" FI="" OS="8" CI="QU01SF1S2032" AW="SSS" SA="1525 Windward Concourse"></root>'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

def map = xml.attributes()
```

The `map` variable would be `[CI:QU01SF1S2032, AW:SSS, TX:0000000000108000001830001, OS:8, FI:, SA:1525 Windward Concourse]`

If it's not an XML, you may follow [ziesemer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867372/581845) and use a regex. A groovier version of his answer that generates a `Map` would be:

```
def input = 'TX="0000000000108000001830001" FI="" OS="8" CI="QU01SF1S2032" AW="SSS" SA="1525 Windward Concourse"'
def match = input =~ /(\w+)="([^"]*)"/

def map = [:]
match.each {
    map[it[1]] = it[2]
}
```

The result of `map` would be the same as before.

Comment: You can also do: `def map = ( match as List ).collectEntries { [ (it[1]):it[2] ] }`

Comment: @tim_yates Nice! I tried calling `collectEntries` on the `match` object, but it doesn't have that method, only the standard iteration methods. I didn't think of converting it into a `List` first. BTW, an `inject` can also do the trick =D

Answer (score 2):

[`StreamTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#quoteChar%28int%29) is fast, although I haven't used the `quoteChar()` feature. Examples may be found [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082174/230513) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/668e4206b35377e2).

Console:

```
TX=0000000000108000001830001
FI=
OS=8
CI=QU01SF1S2032
AW=SSS
SA=1525 Windward Concourse
Count: 6
0.623 ms
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.StringReader;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867325 */
public class TokenizerTest {

    private static final String s = ""
        + "TX=\"0000000000108000001830001\" FI=\"\" OS=\"8\" "
        + "CI=\"QU01SF1S2032\" AW=\"SSS\" SA=\"1525 Windward Concourse\"";
    private static final char equal = '=';
    private static final char quote = '"';
    private static StreamTokenizer tokens = new StreamTokenizer(
        new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s)));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        tokenize();
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((stop - start) / 1000000d + " ms");
    }

    private static void tokenize() {
        tokens.ordinaryChar(equal);
        tokens.quoteChar(quote);
        try {
            int count = 0;
            int token = tokens.nextToken();
            while (token != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
                    System.out.print(tokens.sval);
                    count++;
                }
                if (token == equal) {
                    System.out.print(equal);
                }
                if (token == quote) {
                    System.out.println(tokens.sval);
                }
                token = tokens.nextToken();
            }
            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know about StreamTokenizer

Comment: I just _had_ to try out the `quoteChar()`; more above.

Comment: I think this solution is overly complicated. Unless there is a big performance constraint, I would recomend going with a simpler solution, like using a regex (and if performance _is_ a constraint, it should be profiled to see if this is really faster than a regex, which I doubt).

Comment: @epidemian: Yes, that's why I referenced a convenient [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082174/230513).