# Extracting data from thousands of lines

Tags: java

I have an .obj file, so far I have been using a messy tokenizer to split the lines. I've found this is really inefficient.

```
public static String getSpecificToken(String s, int t) {
    Scanner tokens = new Scanner(s);
    String token = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if(!tokens.hasNext()) { break; }
        token = tokens.next();
    }
    
    tokens.close();
    return token;
}
```

The object file formatting looks like this, I struggle to find the most efficient way to split this.

> v  1.4870 0.3736 2.2576
>
> v  1.5803 0.3451 2.1859
>
> v  1.6275 0.3111 2.2261
>
> v  1.6343 0.0783 2.4352
>
> v  1.5180 0.0644 2.5398
>
> v  1.4568 0.0720 2.5205
>
> v  1.3953 0.0795 2.5013

Comment: Please convince us of the inefficiency with actual benchmark results. I don't see any obvious signs of inefficient code.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to `split` them on space, no need to use `Tokenizer` here. In fact you should avoid using `Tokenizer` as far as possible: -

```
Scanner tokens = new Scanner(s);
String[] tokenArr = tokens.split("\\s+");  // Split on 1 or more space

for (String token: tokenArr) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Comment: But won't that split them by one space only? There can be multiple spaces.

Comment: @user1650289. You can use Regex as Hristo said. I have edited the code.

Comment: Do you honestly expect this to improve performance? But maybe OP is just using wrong terminology.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if that increased performance by any noticeable amount - actually I'd assume it'd less efficient...

Comment: @Voo on second reading, OP is probably not even talking about performance, or is conflating it with code conciseness.

Comment: @user1650289 Split and scanner both use regex, which aren't necessary for the problem - just writing a trivial handwritten parser should beat both of them easily by a good amount thanks to that. But obviously only benchmarking can answer that question definitely.

Comment: @Voo
Do you have an example, I don't know where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082174/230513) compares `java.util.Scanner` with `java.io.StreamTokenizer`, suggesting a slight edge for the latter. You might be able to use a similar approach to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) your use case.